# Click function not working on IE 9/10

Tags: jquery

I have a very simple script for adding a class when I click a button - but its not working on IE. Console says expected ";". whats wrong with this script?

Script

```
$(".navigation-recommended-group").each(function() {
    let panel = this;
    $(this).find(".nsc-button-ghost.nsc-button-primary").click(function() {
           $(panel).toggleClass("open");
           $(this).toggleClass("open");
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="navigation-recommended-group">
<div class="navigation-recommended-group-detail_toggler" data-type="toggleRecommendedGroup">
 <button type="button" tabindex="" class="nsc-button nsc-button-ghost nsc-button-primary">
 <span class="hide">Show More Categories</span>
 <span class="show">Show less categories</span></button>
</div>
</div>
```

Codepen

```
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mxezqE
```

Comment: I think you are missing a `)` on the third line of the code. You need to close the function's `(`.

Comment: change click(function({ to click(function(){

Comment: @rojadesign mad a typo, sorry. Same results though

Comment: what is IE version?

Comment: @sirius2013 works in 11 but not 9 or 10.

Answer (score 0):

can you add your code about DOM ready function?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".navigation-recommended-group").each(function() {
              let panel = this;
              $(this).find(".nsc-button-ghost.nsc-button-primary").click(function( {
                $(panel).toggleClass("open");
                $(this).toggleClass("open");
              });
            });
});
```